# Implementing a 2D Collision method that can tell direction of collision (boxes)

Tags: collision-detection, sfml

Been searching for quite a while now and really struggling to find an easy way, or a good tutorial on how to create a collision detection system which can indicate what side on a box a collision has occurred.

I should specify that I am using SFML2 and their sprites class, this is what I currently use and it just picks up 2 sprites intersecting

```
//check rectangles for collision without taking into account where the collision is
bool Game::isRectCollision(sf::Sprite &sprite1, sf::Sprite &sprite2){

    sf::FloatRect r1=sprite1.getGlobalBounds();
    sf::FloatRect r2=sprite2.getGlobalBounds();
    return r1.intersects(r2);

}
```

Comment: I have always passed the object's movement speed as parameters as well. If `object1.velocity.x > 0`, for example, then `object1` is coming from the left and colliding its right. I wonder if there are alternative ways, tho

Answer (score 1):

The [Separating Axis Theorem](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/collision-detection-using-the-separating-axis-theorem--gamedev-169) might be what you're looking for.
Writing [collision detection using SAT](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) is easier than it seems and allows you to calculate handy things like where exactly they collided as well as the minimum translation vector. Highly recommended for shape collision detection.